# T SQL Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Using MS SQL Server and as part of an ETL process I have FieldA in tblTest1 stored as nvarchar(512).

I'm trying to insert this into FieldB into tblTest2 that is stored as datetime  - however this is failing with the error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

So, before the Insert I have tried the following updates to no avail:

```
UPDATE tblTest1 SET FieldA = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),FieldA, 112) 


UPDATE tblTest1 SET FieldA =  CAST (FieldA AS DATETIME2)

UPDATE tblTest1 SET FieldA =  CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST(FieldA AS DATETIME2), 120)

UPDATE tblTest1 SET FieldA =  CONVERT (DATE,FieldA)
```

Where am I going wrong?  FieldA originally looks likes this: 20081015 (yyyymmdd)

I've also tried to alter FieldA before the insert to no avail:

```
alter table tblTest1  alter column FieldA DateTime
```

Comment: What's the actual contents of `FieldA`? That would help a lot in determining how to properly convert it...

Comment: Those updates work or fail?

Comment: edited to show contents of field A and, yes the updates work fine - its the actual insert that is failing but I want to 'tidy' them up before the insert

Comment: some of the FieldA values not matched with DATE. You can easily check which of them is note match with this script : SELECT * FROM tblTest1 WHERE ISDATE(FieldA)=0

Comment: I ran that and it didn't return any records

Comment: Your current statements are updating `FieldA` by stuffing a `DATETIME` into it -- and it's not a `DATETIME`. This makes no sense -- if the contents are `YYYYMMDD` everywhere, they're already good enough for conversion. Indeed, converting the string to a datetime first and then converting it back again will result in a format that's *less* convertible. To check if `FieldA` contains data anywhere that's not of the expected format, do `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldA NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`, but the "good" rows can be converted directly to `DATETIME`.

Comment: If I run that SELECT I get no records back - I'm lost!  This should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
UPDATE tblTest1
    SET FieldA =  TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, FieldA);
```

Note that this will overwrite values that are not in valid date/time formats.  So, you might want:

```
UPDATE tblTest1
    SET FieldA = TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, FieldA)
    WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, FieldA) IS NOT NULL;
```

Or, even more simply, you might want to dispense with changing the field value at all and use a computed column:

```
alter tbltest1 add fieldA_dt as (TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, FieldA));
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out - it is an issue with field mapping as part of the field mappings.  Thanks to everyone for their help and suggestions.